# Auto-Complete for Standard Email Page

Tags: visualforce, email, jquery

I would like to know how can i get auto-complete functionality for standard email page,  I need auto complete functionality for CC,Additional to, Bcc fields
check my image
[image: Standard Email Page]

MY Visualforce code

```
<apex:form >    
<apex:pageblock id="mail" >
    <apex:pageblockSection columns="2" >
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="To" styleClass="bld"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!to}" rows="2" cols="190"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem> 
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="CC" styleClass="bld"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!cc}" rows="2" cols="190"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>                       
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="BCC" styleClass="bld"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!bcc}" rows="2" cols="190"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" styleClass="bld"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
            <apex:inputText value="{!subject}" size="156"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Message" styleClass="bld"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >                
            <apex:inputTextArea value="{!message}" rows="20" cols="190" richText="false"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>                       
    </apex:pageblockSection>
      <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom" >
        <apex:commandButton value="Send" style="border:outset; background:#A0522D; color:white; font-weight:bold;" action="{!sendeMail}" reRender="output" />
    </apex:pageblockButtons>
</apex:pageblock> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Success/Error Message" id="output">    
    <apex:outputText styleClass="err" value="{!error}"/> 
    <apex:outputText styleClass="success" value="{!successMsg}"/>           
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!addresses}" var="addr">
        <apex:column value="{!addr}"/>
    </apex:pageblocktable>   
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My Apex Class

public class eMail 
{

```
public String to {get;set;}
public String cc {get;set;}
public String bcc {get;set;}
public String message {get;set;}
public String subject {get;set;}
public String error{get;set;} 
public String successMsg{get;set;}
public List<String> addresses {get;set;}
public boolean flagToSendMail;

public void sendeMail()
{
    if(to != '' || cc != '' || bcc != '')
    {
        List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
        List<String> ccAddresses = new List<String>();
        List<String> bccAddresses = new List<String>();

        List<String> tmpAddr = new List<String>();
        if(to.contains(','))
        {
            toAddresses = to.split(',');
            for(String tmp:toAddresses)
            {
                tmpAddr.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        else if(to != '')
        {
            toAddresses.add(to);
            tmpAddr.add(to);
        }
        if(cc.contains(','))
        {
            ccAddresses = cc.split(',');
            for(String tmp:ccAddresses)
            {
                tmpAddr.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        else if(cc != '')
        {
            ccAddresses.add(cc);
            tmpAddr.add(cc);
        }
        if(bcc.contains(','))
        {
            bccAddresses = bcc.split(',');
            for(String tmp:bccAddresses)
            {
                tmpAddr.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        else if(bcc != '')
        {
            bccAddresses.add(bcc);
            tmpAddr.add(bcc);
        }

        /* Checking whether mail ids are valid */
        addresses = tmpAddr;
        for(String tempStr:addresses)
        {
            if(!Pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', tempStr))
            {
                error = 'Check To, CC and BCC addresses';
                successMsg = '';
                flagToSendMail = false;      
                break;          
            }
            else
            {
                flagToSendMail = true;
            }           
        } 

        /* Sending Mail */
        if(flagToSendMail == true)
        {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            if(toAddresses != null)
            {
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            }
            if(toAddresses != null)
            {
                email.setccAddresses(ccAddresses);
            }
            if(toAddresses != null)
            {
                email.setbccAddresses(bccAddresses);
            }
            email.setSubject(subject);  
            email.setHtmlBody(message);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

            error = '';
            successMsg = 'Mail sent successfully to following recipients';
        }                                                                      
    }
    else
    {
        error = 'Please enter To or CC or BCC address'; 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think that is not possible on standard email page. You should create your own visualforce to achieve that.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry and you should post that as the answer.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry For i created a visualforce page for sending email how can i get auto populate functionality i will post my code

Comment: @Sathya please check out my answer and try by using the posted component or if you search a little you'll see many samples. Tell us if you try some and have problems

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible on standard email page. You should create your own Visualforce to achieve that.

You will find on google a lot of good posts about how to make it on visualforce, even a public component: https://github.com/Avinava/Autocomplete-Visualforce-Component-V2